# How to set existing row to unique:user in laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.1

Currently I am doing the form validation using Laravel 5.1. I having problem to add `unique:user` for few row of the data.

I using the example in https://github.com/bestmomo/laravel5-example. By default, the example already set username and email to `unique:user`. Now i wish to set `unique:user` for IC No. and Contact No. After I add the `unique:user`, an error is shown like this:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ic' in 'where clause'    
(SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `ic` = 901234567890)
```

Comment: Can you confirm the column exists? Something may have gone wrong in your migration that added that column. Then try pasting that query in your query browser to confirm it's a DB issue not a code issue.

Comment: OK, thakz. i got it, i refer to wrong table.